# Cant use decimals when defining a value. C#

Tags: c#, int32

I have these two lines:

```
Int32 val3 = 8;
Int32 val4 = 0.66;
```

The first line works, but the second does not. I don't know why, and I don't know how I would go to fix this or what to search for.

Comment: Hi Oscar, the reason this doesn't work is that an integer only represents a whole number. If you need a variable that represents a decimal you should use the decimal, float, or double types. This article goes over the different primitive types and what data they can hold: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types for the meaning of different **Integer** types used with C#.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```cs
double val4 = 0.66
```

Int is for numbers without decimal points...

Answer (score 0):

0.66 is not int32, it is float because it has dot (0.66), only natural numbers are Int
simply use

```
float val4 = 0.66f
```

or

```
var val4 = 0.66
```

C# recognize it correctly as float at compile time

Comment: This answer also works...